# How to load div without click

Tags: javascript, php

Can anybody tell me How to use this code without click?

```
$("#myDiv").load('page_going_somewhere_else.php');
```

I really need it or tell me any other way.

Answer (score 1):

use `.ready()`, for this,

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myDiv").load('page_going_somewhere_else.php');
     });
</script>
```

If you want to load in every x time, try like this, Its bettter to use ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("page_going_somewhere_else.php", function (result) {
            $('#myDiv').html(result);
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer.. Can u tell me how can i update a div after an exact time without reloading web page.

Comment: Hi, Niranjan.. I tried the settimeout() :

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){  alert("Hi.."); $("#div").load('webpage.php'); }, 3000);
 
 });    But this is not able to refresh a div again n again. Do u know the right way to do this.

Comment: you want to do it only once or after every interval of time??

Comment: after every interval ..

Comment: Hay! Niranjan .. I tried this code but its not working and can u tell me for what you  are using result variable?? Is it contains data from database?

Comment: This is a Ajax get call.. In ur. Which file you want u can give... After refresh what ever you want to fetch, echo in that file.... That will come in result variable of Ajax...

Comment: I have connectivity code on the same div and data also in the table form. Then what cal I do?

Answer (score 0):

you can call it in your window.onload event or any other DOM events.

```js
window.onload=function(){
$("#myDiv").load('page_going_somewhere_else.php');
  };
```